# Is there a way to use getters as values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variable-assignment, getter

I have a system that takes some X and Y values for drawing stuff on a canvas. Now, I want a way to set the X or Y of one of the components to a non-static value, by setting its value to a function.

For example, instead of writing something like: `rect.w = 50;`

I would write `rect.w = () => 50 + score;` in order to make the score manipulate the width of the rectangle.

I started writing a TypeScript type definition for these kinds of parameters, but before I actually started implementing it in my code, I realized that this probably isn't a good idea. I'll have to constantly check if these values are functions or numbers any time I need to use them. On the other hand, JS getters, which act like object properties while really just being syntactic sugar for methods, are the perfect answer for this case, but they're meant for objects. Is there a way to implement something like getters for values?

Looking for something like:

```
rect.w = 50;              // valid
rect.w = get () => 50;    // valid, functionally same as above (but pointless)
rect.w = get () => x;     // valid, rect.w returns (() => x)() when checked, acts like a pointer does in other languages
rect.w = get () => 50 + x // valid, rect.w returns (() => x + 50)()
```

Comment: Simply always make them functions. `() => 50` is not pointless, it helps to maintain the consistent interface you're longing for.

Comment: In some cases, that would be preferrable, but (in my case) when the majority of values in the code are static, like the MIDI 0-127 note a certain button plays, designing the whole thing around dynamic values just because there might someday be a button that plays the note () => Math.floor(Math.random()*128) is a bit too convoluted. The getters are like the exception, not the rule.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use them everywhere you can, but everywhere you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok you want to use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

```js
const rect = {
  x: 99
};

Object.defineProperty(rect , 'w', { get() { return this.x + 50 } });

console.log(rect.w);
```

Comment: Yes, except I can't just make `rect = ` an object containing the getter. `rect` is an instance of a class and already has x set to a number like 0 or 50. The same way you can assign a function to a variable like `const x = () => { /**/ }`, is there a way to assign a getter function like that?

Comment: Ok I get it now, see edit

Comment: Just tried it, and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks!